# Is there a way to use space between buttons in landscape

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, s60

After much digging I've realised there is no Qt-way to use 3 middle buttons in landscape mode in S50v5, however I don't like to waste this precious space. I've tried to place my widgets there but menu bar is on top and widgets aren't visible.

Is there any way to utilise this space without using native Symbian APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Controlling the stock softkeys in Qt is a pain. The strategy I have used is to make the `QMainWindow` full-screen with `showFullScreen()` which allows you to use the softkey space yourself. You will have to make sure any widgets you create are ultimately parents of the main window, and be mindful of [this bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-13156) when creating pop-ups.

Comment: It answers my question in no way. BTW controlling two standard softkeys in Qt is easy.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. You say you've tried to use your own widgets 'there' (in place of the softkeys, I presume) - the method I mention above certainly allows you to place softkeys there. I have a couple of apps that do this, replacing the system softkeys with my own (and replacing the menu, which is also very easy).

Comment: I've tried to place my widgets between standard buttons, not instead.